# Installing vsftp on centos 5.5 (ftp command not found)

Tags: centos, ftp

I installed Vsftp in CentOS 5.5 Box, and configured it but when I type a command

```
ftp localhost
```

I get ftp command not found. here is my vsftpd.conf file

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022

#pasv_min_port=3000
#pasv_max_port=3050


#anon_upload_enable=YES
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
"/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf" 125L, 4703C
xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES

#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever

#xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog

xferlog_std_format=YES

#idle_session_timeout=600

#data_connection_timeout=120

#nopriv_user=ftpsecure

#async_abor_enable=YES

#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails
chroot_list_enable=No
# (default follows)
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
#ls_recurse_enable=YES

listen=YES

#listen_ipv6=YES
dirlist_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES 
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have not installed this package or it was a minimal installation.
Please install this by using: `yum install ftp`.

The server config has nothing to do with the client, these are two separate packages.

Comment: ok thanks. but still I have one more problem, I i'm not able to connect from remotely from my desktop to server.

Comment: @makdotgnu : Different problem, different question. Accept this answer if it solved your problem.